# Tensor Flow Explicit Device Requirement Error

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to run the CIFAR10 tutorial with the training code on one gpu and the eval code on the other. I know for sure I have two gpus on my computer, and I can test this by running the simple examples here: https://www.tensorflow.org/how_tos/using_gpu/index.html

However, using a `with device('/gpu:0')` does not work for most variables in the CIFAR example. I tried a whole lot of combinations of different variables on gpu vs. cpu, or all the variables on one or the other. Always the same error for some variable, something like this:

```
Cannot assign a device to node 'shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue': Could not satisfy explicit device specification '/gpu:0'
```

Is this possibly a bug in Tensor Flow or am I missing something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Could not satisfy explicit device specification` means you do not have the corresponding device. Do you actually have a CUDA-enabled GPU on your machine?

**UPDATE:** As it turned out in the discussion below, this error is also raised if the particular operation (in this case, `RandomShuffleQueue`) cannot be executed on the GPU, because it only has a CPU implementation.

If you are fine with TensorFlow choosing a device for you (particularly, falling back to CPU when no GPU implementation is available), consider setting `allow_soft_placement` in your configuration, as per [this article](http://www.tensorflow.org/how_tos/using_gpu/index.html):

```py
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(
    allow_soft_placement=True, log_device_placement=True))
```

Comment: I know it uses the GPU on my machine. It logs that it does. I can have it run without explicitly labeling which GPU to use and it will try to use /gpu:0. This works fine. I also know that in the general case for simple variables I can explicitly use a particular GPU, like that described in the link I put.

Comment: The problem is particular to the way the code is working in the tutorial

Comment: which particular line does it fail to (I know you said there are several, but at least one example would be helpful). Could it be that the command it fails to can only be ran on CPU?

Comment: Well for instance if I surround the `images, labels = cifar10.distorted_inputs()` line in a `with tf.device('/gpu:0)' block it fails first on the RandomShuffleQueue generated the shuffle_batch in _generate_image_and_label_batch

Comment: what happens if you surround the same line with `cpu:0` instead (or whatever the correct syntax for cpu is)? I suspect that `distorted_inputs` just doesn't have a GPU implementation.

Comment: Yeah it seems like that's working. So I have to try to track down every variable and test it? Is is possible that some variables are only able to use the gpu if later variables that depend on them are also on the gpu?

Comment: TensorFlow will move data between CPU and GPU. So if something that can be executed on GPU depends on data that can be only created on CPU, the data will be moved to GPU automatically.
Also, you don't have to track it down, just use the config option from my answer. If I understand it correctly, it will fall back to CPU if GPU cannot be used silently.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96927/discussion-between-bschreck-and-ishamael).